# Is it possible to set a different polygon in a wpf data template trigger

Tags: wpf

I want to display a different polygon based on a datatemplate trigger.

(PS: don't look at the points collection for Circle, I know that doesn't look like a circle at all ;-))

```
<ContentControl.Resources>
    <Polygon 
        x:Key="Circle"  
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="DarkGray"
        Width="25" Height="25" Points=" 0,50 25,100 75,100" />        
    <Polygon 
        x:Key="Hexagon" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="DarkGray"
        Width="25" Height="25" Points=" 0,50 25,100 75,100 100,50 75,0 25,0 0,50" />

    <Polygon Name="path" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="DarkGray"
        Width="25" Height="25" />
```

Then I want to change the polygon on a data template trigger.

```
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SimulationType}" Value="{x:Static vm:SimulationType.ServerSimulated}">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Points" Value="{StaticResource Hexagon}"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SimulationType}" Value="{x:Static vm:SimulationType.ServerInSimulation}">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Points" Value="{StaticResource Circle}"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
            
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

This will throw a runtime exception because I am trying to put an entire `Polygon`  in a `PointsCollection` which is not possible. But how on earth do I achieve what I am looking for?

I can't seem to figure out if, and how, to define a `PointsCollection` in xaml. Neither is it possible to create a data template trigger on an entire `Polygon`.

How do I replace the points of a polygon in a data template trigger?

Comment: There should be a Path element, and you would set its Data property in a DataTrigger. Data is a Geometry, e.g. a PathGeometry or an EllipseGeometry etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the target is a `Polygon`, you can define a `PointCollections` as a collection of `Point`s and set it to `Points` Property.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <PointCollection x:Key="HexagonPoints">
        <Point X="0" Y="50"/>
        <Point X="25" Y="100"/>
        <Point X="75" Y="100"/>
        <Point X="100" Y="50"/>
        <Point X="75" Y="0"/>
        <Point X="25" Y="0"/>
        <Point X="0" Y="50"/>
    </PointCollection>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds promising! Thanks. Always have some trouble figuring out how it was supposed to work with WFP/xaml. Will try this next week and try to remember to get back here to accept the answer!